# how To Have complete Access to Instagram API (Live/Sandbox)

Tags: api, instagram, sandbox, live, instagram-api

I'm new to Instagram API and my question is how to get complete access to Instagram's API without any limitations - like API's that any other Third-Party Client Apps Like (6tag /ink361.com/insta(X))uses .i want to give my   users complete access so they can (like - repost - regram - Edit - ...).
and as I read in the official documentation there is a Sandbox / Live Permission/Condition that developers can get to have that kind of Access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to built an app similar to the core functionalities of Instagram (or most of it!).

As you have said, they have introduced Sandbox features post November 17th, so any app created after that date will be running in Sandbox mode until you give it for a review.

Few things to note here:

1. They are restructuring their APIs, meaning there are lot more restrictions and validations!
2. I'm not sure, but if you search on Google about their restructuring of APIs, it clearly states that Instagram is trying to block an app which has most of the core functionalities of it - likes/posts/feeds etc. This is to secure their users' data and prevent malicious activities.
3. Most of the endpoints are restricted and some of the old ones are slowly being deprecated.

So, I guess from now on you can't build an app on Instagram which is similar to theirs. Regarding the existing apps which does the same, they have to remove those deprecated endpoints as these new features will be imposed on them post 2016!

At the moment, you can the endpoints available to you are documented on http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/.

Hope it answers all your queries!

Comment: Exactly, i want to create a app like ( Famousgram on IOS ) .
so Users can Follow and get Coin and losing coin to get many followers ,

Comment: Ok, you might create an app like that. As from the app description, they are using some exchange logic to build more followers on Instagram.

Comment: You can simply call Insta endpoints like users to fetch followers data and simply keep a tab on it. Then use your logic to attract X numbers of followers for your user based on the coin value, (post/put). Hope it helps!